# Saving an index from a list in a while loop in Python

Tags: python, file, indexing, while-loop, readline

How do you save an index of a list while in a 'while' loop?

Basically I am running through a text file and I want to identify a date, and then afterwards get the information that corresponds to that date which is the line below. So far I can match the date entered to the line with that date but don't know how to save that line so I can get he information from the line below.

```
f = open("studentinfo.txt")
#ask for date
d = input("Enter the date:")
date = [d]
#check to see if date is avialable
while True:
    line = f.readline().split()
    if line:
        if line == date:
            print(line)
            #save data in here, index etc
    else:
        break
        print("No data available")
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you save an index of a list while in a 'while' loop. Basically I am running through a text file and I want to identify a date, and then afterwards get the information that corresponds to that date which is the line below. So far I can match the date entered to the line with that date but don't know how to save that line so I can get he information from the line below.

```
f = open("studentinfo.txt")
#ask for date
d = input("Enter the date:")
date = [d]
#check to see if date is avialable

for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    if line:
        if line == date:
            print(line)
            #save data in here, index etc
    else:
        break
        # print("No data available") <-- check indents unreachable code
```

Comment: It seems to me, `print("No data available")` should have another indent.

Comment: in the original question also that's unreachable code, I left it as is. But let's remove it

Answer (score 0):

You have to track the index manually, i.e.:

```
i = 0
while True:
    # Do stuff.
    i += 1
```